# Table in Latex, created in Excel2Latex

Tags: tables

Firstly, thank you for an answer from the previous post.

Here is a table that I have created, is there a way that I can have the actual table to start at the left of the text and end at the right of the text.

To make each of the columns slightly larger so it matches each side.

Thanks in advance.

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}
\centering

\centering
\caption*{\textbf{Summary Statistics, Monthly Excess Stock Returns\\S\&P 500 and US XYZ}\\
\centering

This table reports summary statistics for XYZ currency excess returns (in percent) for industrialized countries. The excess return is the return on the broad market index and 123 XYZ in excess of the three-month US treasury bill rate. Data are from DataSource. FRED, Federal Reserve Economic.


    \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
    \hline
          & Mean  & Std.  &       & Mean  & Std. \\
    \hline
    \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .439,  .753}{\textbf{S\&P 500}} & 0.01  & 9.24  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.52  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.98  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.1   & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.21  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 6.9   & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.87  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 6.14  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.35  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 6.31  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 8.61  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 6.1   & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 9.42  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 10.83 & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.3   & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 5.73  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.59  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.23  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.69  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 4.77  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 9.29  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 10.52 & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 6.53  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 8.13  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
\hline
    \end{tabular}%

  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

Also I would appreciate if anyone could tell me how to move the :* next to Table 1.

[image: How it looks now]

Comment: Please do post compilable code. What we need to help you is a so called [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: I use Scientific workplace, so I am only interested in the table.

Comment: You could use `tabularx` like this: `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*6{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}`

Comment: @ZarinaAkhtar And we're interested in helping you, which is easier if you provide us with compilable code.

Comment: I do get that you want it differently but I dont understand how you want it. Sorry

Comment: Take a look here on how to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`, including every necessary package you need for your code snippet to run, but *nothing more* than the bare necessities.

Comment: see my answer to your previous question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The columns can be spread using the [`tabularx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package. Per your example I have centered the caption, you can remove this in the `\captionsetup` call.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}

% Remove "justification=centering" if the caption should not be centered
\captionsetup{font=bf, justification=centering}
\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0,.439,.753}

\begin{document}

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}

    \caption{Summary Statistics, Monthly Excess Stock Returns \\ S\&P 500 and US XYZ}%
    \label{tab:addlabel}

    This table reports summary statistics for XYZ currency excess returns (in percent) for industrialized countries. The excess return is the return on the broad market index and 123 XYZ in excess of the three-month US treasury bill rate. Data are from DataSource. FRED, Federal Reserve Economic.

    \medskip

    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c*5{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
    \hline
             & Mean  & Std.  &          & Mean  & Std. \\
    \hline
    \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{S\&P 500}} & 0.01  & 9.24  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.52  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.98  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.1   & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.21  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 6.9   & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.87  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 6.14  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.35  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 6.31  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 8.61  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 6.1   & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 9.42  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 10.83 & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.3   & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 5.73  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.59  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.23  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.69  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 4.77  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 9.29  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 10.52 & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 6.53  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 8.13  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image: LaTeX]

Answer (score 1):

The star comes from the command `\caption*{...}`. To get rid of it you can either load the package "caption" with `\usepackage{caption}`, since the star command is defined there, or you can just ommit the star and use `\caption{...}` instead.

In order to specify the width (in this case `\linewidth`)  of the table you have to use:

```
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{cccccc}
...
\end{tabular*}
```

Instead of

```
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
...
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Ok, are you saying you don't know how to spread it across the page.

Comment: @ZarinaAkhtar in case this answer helps you, you can upvote it, but accept it only if it fully answers your original question.

Comment: @ZarinaAkhtarI am saying that SWP and Excel2LaTeX are a messy combination. You should also clean up the code a little, e.g. `\centering` appears three times.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest `tabular*`, with a generous amount of space in the middle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\captionsetup{font=bf}

\newcommand{\specialcell}[2]{\color{#1}\fontseries{b}\selectfont #2}

\definecolor{tableblue}{rgb}{0,.439,.753}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Summary Statistics, Monthly Excess Stock Returns \\ S\&P 500 and US XYZ}
\label{tab:addlabel}

This table reports summary statistics for XYZ currency excess returns (in percent) for 
industrialized countries. The excess return is the return on the broad market index 
and 123 XYZ in excess of the three-month US treasury bill rate. Data are from DataSource. 
FRED, Federal Reserve Economic.

\medskip

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  @{\hspace{6em}}
  l
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  @{}
}
\toprule
& {Mean} & {Std.} & & {Mean} & {Std.} \\
\midrule
\specialcell{tableblue}{S\&P 500}
             & 0.01  & 9.24  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.52  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.98  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.1   & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.21  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 6.9   & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.87  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 6.14  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.35  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 6.31  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 8.61  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 6.1   & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 9.42  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 10.83 & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.3   & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 5.73  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.59  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.23  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 7.69  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 4.77  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 9.29  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 10.52 & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 6.53  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
    S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 8.13  & S\&P 500 & 0.01  & 0.01 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note also the use of `caption` to avoid `\textbf` in the caption text, which is wrong. For good alignment in the figures, I used `siunitx` features. With `\fontseries{b}`, the colored entry is not wider than the others in the same column, but still distinctly boldface.

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer. Did not know about `\fontseries{b}`. Thanks!